# How do I create an uncacheable field plugin base?

Tags: views, 8, entities, caching

I created a custom field plugin base for show an additional data column in a  view.

In my FieldPluginBase Class, I define the value of my additional data column for each row of my view (one row equal one node). The datas depends some node parameter.

My problem is users can often changes nodes parameters, but when the user access to my view after change a parameter of a node, the additional column show old data.

I notice when I clear website cache, the view show the new value.

This is the code of my class, can you tell me what must I do for the view shows all the time the newest value of the node in my field plugin base ?

```
class MyFieldPluginBaseCustom extends FieldPluginBase {

    ...
    public function render(ResultRow $values) {
        //do some work with the current node (the current row view)
        if(node_parameter_test_isOK() == true) 
            return "string A";
        }    
        else{
            return "string B";
        }
    }

    // 0 : the view shows a list of node
    // the view ; 
    // (nodeid - mycustom Field Plugind)
    // node1 - "string B"
    // node2 - "string A"
    // node3 - "string B"
    ...
    // nodeN - "string B"

    // 1 : a user change the parameter of the node3

    // (2) : then, when the user access to the view page, the view must show  
    // node1 - "string B"
    // node2 - "string A"
    // node3 - "string A"
    ...
    // nodeN - "string B"

    // 2 : However, the view hasn't been updated and show again (unless I clear caches via drush cr by example)
    // node1 - "string B"
    // node2 - "string A"
    // node3 - "string B" // row not updated
    ...
    // nodeN - "string B"
    ...
}
```

Comment: did you disable the views caching ??

Comment: Its work when I disable cache of the view (from the view edit ui) thanks ! but is it possible to disable cache only for my field not for the entire view ?

Comment: I haven't tried this but it should work if you encounter any error please let me know

Comment: Hi @user2137454. Are you got any solution for this problem. I am facing same issue.

Answer (score 1):

May be you can try :

```
use Drupal\Core\Cache\CacheableDependencyInterface;
use Drupal\views\Plugin\views\field\UncacheableFieldHandlerTrait;

class MyFieldPluginBaseCustom extends FieldPluginBase implements CacheableDependencyInterface  {

    ...
    public function render(ResultRow $values) {
        //do some work with the current node (the current row view)
        if(node_parameter_test_isOK() == true) 
            return "string A";
        }    
        else{
            return "string B";
        }
    }
  public function getCacheMaxAge() {
    return 0;
  }
  public function getCacheContexts() {
    return [];
  }
  public function getCacheTags() {
    return [];
      }
}
```